# i got error Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 4): TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, json, react-native

so i have a problem with my json in react native, i tried using thunderclient for my API and there's no problem, but when i wrote this code

```
`async klikEdit(kdpemb){
    await fetch(this.url+"/?op=detail&kdpemb="+kdpemb)
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((json)=>{
        this.setState({
            username:json.data.result[0].username,
            password:json.data.result[0].password,
            nip:json.data.result[0].nip,
            nama_guru:json.data.result[0].nama_guru,
            unit_kerja:json.data.result[0].unit_kerja,
            jabatan:json.data.result[0].jabatan,
            kdjurusan_tugas:json.data.result[0].kdjurusan_tugas,
            idEdit:kdpemb
        })
    })
}`
```

it showing error
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 4):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

but the problem is, each of the variable username, password have a value. any solution?

sorry for my bad english

i want to put a value, each value to a textinput, each textinput already declared using uusername, password etc for the state

Comment: is `json.data.result` an Array? Does it contain at least 1 object? are you able to show the actual content (not a guess, actual content - obviously with any personal data obfuscated) of `json`

Comment: it's like this
function detail(){
global $koneksi;
$kdpemb = $_GET['kdpemb'];
$sql = "select * from tbl_pemb where kdpemb = '$kdpemb'";
$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$hasil = array(
'kdpemb' => $fetch['kdpemb'],
'username' => $fetch['username'],
'password' => $fetch['password'],
'nip' => $fetch['nip'],
'nama_guru' => $fetch['nama_guru'],
'unit_kerja' => $fetch['unit_kerja'],
'jabatan' => $fetch['jabatan'],
'kdjurusan_tugas' => $fetch['kdjurusan_tugas'],
);
}
$data['data']['result'] = $hasil;
echo json_encode($data);}

Comment: I don't know what `like this` means ... clearly there is nothing in the array

Comment: it's like this function detail(){ global $koneksi; $kdpemb = $_GET['kdpemb']; $sql = "select * from tbl_pemb where kdpemb = '$kdpemb'"; $query = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql); while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ $hasil = array( 'kdpemb' => $fetch['kdpemb'], 'username' => $fetch['username'], 'password' => $fetch['password'], 'nip' => $fetch['nip'], 'nama_guru' => $fetch['nama_guru'], 'unit_kerja' => $fetch['unit_kerja'], 'jabatan' => $fetch['jabatan'], 'kdjurusan_tugas' => $fetch['kdjurusan_tugas'], ); } $data['data']['result'] = $hasil; echo json_encode($data);}

Comment: sorry i accidentally press enter

Comment: please put the contents of `json.data.result` **in the question** - not the php code that creates it - that is not helpful at all - from what I can see `data.result` won't be an Array at all

Comment: try removing `[0]` in your code

Comment: ah sorry, i'm still learning. i don't know which one

i tried removing the index. it's still like that

Comment: ah sorry, i'm still learning. i don't know which one

i tried removing the index. it's still like that

Comment: `i don't know which one i tried` **ALL OF THEM** - since `json.data.result[0]` is clearly NOT an array

Comment: so maybe i need to remove the array index then eh. ill try that again

Answer (score 0):

As per your provided response, `json.data.result` is not an array and hence you are getting `json.data.result[0]` as `undefined`. So instead of `json.data.result[0].username` use `json.data.result.username`.

Happy coding :)

Comment: {"data": {"result": {"kdpemb": "188","username": "000","password":"000","nip": "123123","nama_guru": "Arief Febrian","unit_kerja": "WB2","jabatan":"Guru","kdjurusan_tugas": "0"}}}

it's the respone from my thunderclient to http://localhost/api_test/index.php?op=detail&kdpemb=188